# Bootstrap: nav-link does not get hidden when dropdown-item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Following is what I would like to achieve - when a dropdown-item from navbar gets selected, complete **BOTH** of the following 2 actions:

- Go to the div with the target id
- Roll up the navbar to the initial state (hide it back to the fully rolled upstate)

As it turns out, I was able to do only one or the other, but not both. Could someone please help provide guidance on how I can achieve both points? I believe that the first dropdown-item anchor should do it, but, for some reason, it doesn't go to the targetId after it rolls up the navbar. The anchor takes me to the target only if I remove the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"`, which is what the second anchor shows, but then the navbar doesn't roll up.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu shadow rounded" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#targetId" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">nav-link does get hidden, but it doesn't hit the target</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#targetId">Hits the target, but the nav-link does not get hidden</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- navbar ends here -->
<div id="targetId">Content</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Javascript` for that.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.custom_collapse').forEach(cur => {
  cur.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.navbar_collapse').classList.remove('show');
  });
});
```

```css
#targetId {
    /* JUST FOR SEE TARGET */
    margin-top: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar_collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu shadow rounded" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item custom_collapse" href="#targetId">nav-link does get hidden, but it doesn't hit the target</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item custom_collapse" href="#targetId">Hits the target, but the nav-link does not get hidden</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- navbar ends here -->
<div id="targetId">Content</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nisharg! While the code snippet works as expected in the embedded window you included (which is why I marked the question as resolved), when I put the code in my html file and open it with a browser, the javascript piece doesn't seem to work. As a quick way of testing I included the javascript you shared within the <script> tag in the head of my html file. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here. Does any reason of why the javascript function may not be running on my end come to mind?

Comment: you can test your javascript file, by making `console.log()` on it. If console log works so, check event listener is works or not

Comment: Ok I figured it out - the javascript function that you listed has to be placed at the end of the body, after all the nvabar html. I had it at the top and it was executing before html was "seen", which was resulting in empty NodeList. In other words, if we imagine that the blocks in your answer were named as 1,2 and 3, the right sequence in order for the solution to work is: 2, 3, 1. Thanks for suggesting console.log(), it helped me figure out what the issue was.

Comment: Glad to help you